# Problem loading an image dynamically with Vue & Webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli

I started building an application with the Vue CLI, and I have the following code snippet in a component:

```
<template>
  <div v-loading="loading">
    <el-carousel :interval="4000" type="card" height="350px">
      <el-carousel-item v-for="element in persons" :key="element.id">
            <div class="testimonial-persons">
                <el-avatar :size="80">
                    <img :src="require('@assets/testimonial/'+ element.photo)"> 
                </el-avatar>
                <h3>{{element.name}}</h3>
                <h4>{{element.occupation}}</h4>
                <hr style="width:50%;">
                <p>"{{element.comment}}"</p>
            </div>
      </el-carousel-item>
    </el-carousel>
  </div>
</template>
```

When the page is loaded I make a request for an API that returns an array of objects that I store in `persons` to iterate over the template.

**Persons**

```
[ 
    { 
        "testimonial_id": "2",
        "persons_id": "1",
        "id": "1", 
        "name": "Tom lima", 
        "occupation": "CEO / Pugmania",
        "comment": "Simply the best customer service and attention to detail.",
        "photo": "20200320193143R7pChVea3IkmujRRmS.png" 
    },

]
```

Everything works normally, the problem is with the image loading.

[image]

When I enter the image name manually it works.

```
  <img src="@assets/testimonial/20200320193143R7pChVea3IkmujRRmS.png">
```

> Does anyone have any idea how to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template is correct except that you're missing a `/` following the `@`.  It should be:

```html
<img :src="require('@/assets/testimonial/' + element.photo)">
```

This would be needed for the manual usage too, so maybe you left it out when you converted it to a dynamic path.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put in the question that I'm using an alias in @assets :) is a directory that is one level above the src folder. https://imgur.com/eRmHt7a for that reason I didn't put /

Comment: when I put the / he doesn't find :( https://imgur.com/tvqQ55w

Comment: That's an extremely confusing custom Webpack alias to not mention, because Vue-CLI uses `@` as a default `src` alias.  So this means you created the first alias, the `@` alias, unnecessarily, since it already exists.  Finally, the error message indicates that Webpack does not recognize your `@assets` alias when using `require`.  I would not use `@` in any custom aliases to avoid confusion.

Comment: Also, by using a custom assets folder outside of Vue-CLI's src assets, you are bypassing and missing out on Vue's asset bundling convenience. I guess the question is why are you doing it this way? I would suggest moving your assets into `src/assets`, remove your custom aliases, and use my answer syntax.

Comment: Perfect @Dan thank you! I will follow your recommendations! is that I’m relatively new to vue and I haven’t yet managed to absorb all the documentation and best practices... I'm migrating a project using codeigniter and jquery and I tried to reuse the structure that I already had of the assets so I made this alias :) thanks again o/

Comment: You're welcome, it's a good effort.  Let me know if you have any trouble or if it solves your issue.  Also, if your `assets` was actually in the root like your `src` (i know you said it was above it), then this alias would have worked:  `'@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/uploads/')`.  (But don't do it this way.)

Comment: thank you very much for your attention! I'll explain a little better what I'm trying to do ... The basic architecture of my application follows the codeigniter boilerplate as follows:
https://imgur.com/HbshQue  Within the application I have the models, views and controllers and I created the vue structure inside too, getting this way:https://imgur.com/lruSGvs  I delete the dist directory and I'm doing the build directly inside the views directory, that way I already load the html files generated in the build with the codeigniter.

Comment: The assets directory I created at the root of the document, at the same application and system level. What problem am I facing now? Well, my application is basically based on uploading files ... and my backend functions in codeigniter write these files into the assets directory, something like this:https://imgur.com/UfokrNG when I try to search for these files in the assets directory with vue I have the problem I mentioned above.
we assume that I start recording the files in the src / assets directory .. that way vue should be able to find the files normally, right?

Comment: but what's the other problem there ... when my code goes to production it goes without the src/assets directory and my backend will keep trying to write the files in that directory that no longer exists ... and that's when I got a little lost. I don't know if it was clear :) Thxx a lot!

Comment: I see.  Frontend source folders are not really a good fit for this scenario.  I think it's best to simply create:  `<img :src="'http://<myserver>/<path>/' + element.photo" />`

Comment: I think this will be a good solution! I will try to implement this tomorrow! thank you again
o/

Comment: I tested it today and it worked perfectly! woooo \o/!

Comment: Woo.  If my answer solved it, please mark accepted/vote.  You can do that like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png